# Deferred tasks golang

Tags: algorithm, go, redis, scheduled-tasks

I have a task, sending a "push notification", I need to delay the task for 10 seconds.

Full description of the task:
There are two events that come from the same `HTTP/S METHOD POST` request, `message.new` and `message.read`. When the `message.new` event arrives, it must be added to the repository, but before adding it you must check if there is such an event in the queue, otherwise you must replace the old event with the new one. When `message.read` arrives, the event `message.new` must be removed from the queue if it exists. The `message.new` event will remain in the repository for 10 seconds after it is added, then it must be sent to the notification service.

At this point there are several options for a solution:

1. Time wheel`algorithm`https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-01/timingwheel/`.
2. RabbitMQ - after 10 seconds the data will be written from one queue to another, from which the data will be read.
3. Cron

Full description of the solution which is:
When an event arrives, the data goes to the golang channel, then the background method writes the data to the in-memory storage, so that not every event is sent to the storage for processing, but in batches. But the problem is I don't know what storage to use exactly to store the event for 10 seconds and then send this event to notification service, maybe there are task schedulers, or queues (except kafka, because it is too heavy solution), with which I can solve this problem.

I explain why I need to keep the data for 10 seconds. 10 seconds gives a user to read a message, or another user to send a new message, in case a new message comes to the same user then I replace the old event with the new one.

I will also add that when these events come, I can get both chatID and userID from the body of the request - that is, the identifier of the user who is writing the message.

Maybe someone has faced similar problems and can give a solution in golang

Comment: I think database record with a trigger time + cron would be the way. You could remove the record when message.read is received. If message.new is received, then replace.

A cron could run every second or lower (using time.Ticker?) to fetch and send everything to notification service for which trigger time is in past.

Comment: @JeechuDeka, Thanks for the option. But at the moment I decided to do a little differently, through channels and redis, as well as in memory buffers for background methods to handle not a single event, but in packets.